# alternative of enumerate() in python

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I want to access the index without using enumerate in this code

```
def check(text):
    stack=[]
    index=[]
    for i, ch in enumerate(text):
        if ch in ['{','(']:
            stack.append(ch)
            index.append(i)
```

here is my approch

```
def check(text):
    stack=[]
    index=0
    x=range(len(text))

    for i in x:
        if i in ['{','(']:
            stack.append(i)
            index+=1
```

is it correct?

Comment: Why not use enumerate? It's simple and effective.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 I want to use a basic approach.

Comment: @NailaGani, note that our scope is limited to "**practical**, answerable" questions. Intentionally making your code more complicated to avoid using a standard-library facility is not exactly practical.

Comment: I think OP wants to try coding it themselves.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8, sure, but that doesn't mean it's our obligation to support them in their personal training exercise -- if it isn't something that might reasonably be used in practical, production-focused code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point.

Comment: i'm not allowed to use enumerate :')

Comment: It should be `if text[i] in ['{','(']:` as `i` is the index into the input string.

Comment: "is it correct?" Well, what happened when you **tried it**? "i'm not allowed to" Well, you should say so up front, then. The context of "I am doing this for school work" is important here.

Comment: Have you considered using `zip(range(len(text)), text)` as a drop-in substitute for `enumerate(text)`?

Answer (score 1):

`for i in x` will return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4..., not the text. Also, your `index` is completely useless in your current code.
Also, your `index` is in the wrong place.

The easiest way to fix the code is just to do this:

```
def check(text):
    stack = []
    index = 0
    for char in text:
        if char in ["{", "("]:
            stack.append(char)
        index+=1
```

Note that `x` is never used.

Thanks to @G. Anderson for the fix (index in the wrong place)!

Also side note: is this for an ide? :P

Comment: Shouldn't the `index+=1` be ouside the `if:`? Otherwise the index will only go up when one of the characters is found

Comment: Good point. Missed that.